# The Dart Analyzer has terminated

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Every time I open Visual studio code I get this error, and can not continue programming my app. I did some googleing and looked at other issue son Stack and attempted to delete the contents of the flutter cahce folder, that did not work. I tried pub get, that also didnt fix the issue.

Flutter Doctor also shows no issues.

When I look at my log I see this:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"textDocument/publishDiagnostics","params":{"diagnostics":[],"uri…
[4:56:44 PM] [Analyzer] [Error] Unhandled exception:
Bad state: Suspected cycle. [(uri: package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart, path: /Users/mike_jones/Documents/development/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/flutter_test.dart), (uri: package:flutter_test/src/test_text_input.dart, path: /Users/mike_jones/Documents/development/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/test_text_input.dart), (uri: package:flutter/services.dart, path: /Users/mike_jones/Documents/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/services.dart), (uri: package:fl…
[4:56:44 PM] [Analyzer] [Error] /src/src/src/_goldens_io.dart), (uri: package:flutter/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/_goldens_io.dart, path: /Users/mike_jones/Documents/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/_goldens_io.dart), (uri: package:flutter/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/…
[4:56:44 PM] [Analyzer] [Error] c/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/_goldens_io.dart, path: /Users/mike_jones/Documents/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/_goldens_io.dart), (uri: package:flutter/src/src/src/…
[4:56:44 PM] [Analyzer] [Error] c/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/_goldens_io.dart, path: /Users/mike_jones/Documents/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/_goldens_io.dart), (uri: package:flutter/…
[4:56:44 PM] [Analyzer] [Error] c/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/_goldens_io.dart, path: /Users/mike_jones/Documents/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/s…
[4:56:44 PM] [Analyzer] [Error] rc/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/_goldens_io.dart), (uri: package:flutter/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/…
[4:56:44 PM] [Analyzer] [Error] c/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/_goldens_io.dart, path: /Users/mike_jones/Documents/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/s…
[4:56:44 PM] [Analyzer] [Error] src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/_goldens_io.dart, path: /Users/mike_jones/Documents/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src…
[4:56:44 PM] [Analyzer] [Error] src/src/src/src/src/_goldens_io.dart, path: /Users/mike_jones/Documents/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src…
[4:56:44 PM] [Analyzer] [Error] src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/_goldens_io.dart, path: /Users/mike_jones/Documents/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src…
[4:56:44 PM] [Analyzer] [Error] rt, path: /Users/mike_jones/Documents/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/s…
[4:56:44 PM] [Analyzer] [Error] src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/_goldens_io.dart, path: /Users/mike_jones/Documents/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src…
[4:56:44 PM] [Analyzer] [Error] c/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/_goldens_io.da…
[4:56:44 PM] [Analyzer] [Error] c/src/src/_goldens_io.dart, path: /Users/mike_jones/Documents/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/s…
[4:56:44 PM] [Analyzer] [Error] rc/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/s…
[4:56:44 PM] [Analyzer] [Error] es/flutter/lib/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/s…
[4:56:44 PM] [Analyzer] [Error] c/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/_goldens_io.dart, path: /Users/mike_jones/Documents/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/s…
[4:56:44 PM] [Analyzer] [Error] /src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/_goldens_io.dart), (uri: package:flutter/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/sr…
[4:56:44 PM] [Analyzer] [Error] src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/_goldens_io.dart, path: /Users/mike_jones/Documents/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src…
[4:56:44 PM] [Analyzer] [Error] c/src/src/src/src/src/_goldens_io.dart, path: /Users/mike_jones/Documents/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/s…
[4:56:44 PM] [Analyzer] [Error] /src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src…
[4:56:44 PM] [Analyzer] [Error] rc/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/s…
[4:56:44 PM] [Analyzer] [Error] src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/_goldens_io.dart, path: /Users/mike_jones/Documents/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src/src…
[4:56:44 PM] [Analyzer] [Error] available_declarations.dart:755:10)
```

Comment: ... are your paths actually like that? do you have any recursive symlinks or something?

Comment: your path kinda sus

Comment: @user not how to check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I just needed to run:

```
flutter pub cache clean
```